# Excellence? Perfection? Success?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, letters

**What are you striving for?**

> 1. ACENT / CENOS / AEGNTT / ACGNNOTT
> 2. EEEJNSWY / AEEHIMNPRSW / AACHILNNORRT / AAEERLW / KNORWY / AGIINRV / AACEHMSSSTTU / AAEINNNPSVY / EGGIOR / CCCEINOTTU / AALMNRY
> 3. AACDEEHLLOOPRRSST / ACT / GMPSY / CDMNRUU / AQTUZ / ACCELT / AOPZ / AAIPTT
> 4. AHLLOW / CEERSS / EHINPX / AAABKZ / FIR
> 5. AIINU / HOU / AAEHKLOO / IMU / AAKU / AKLMOO
> 6. DNOR / KNOPTY / AENNOOSS / ENNX / ENO
> 7. AMR / EHRT / EIJPRU / CEMRRY / ANSUU / ESUV
> 8. EIMSSW / DFOO / EGLLOS / AADFLN / BIMORR / EMRY / IIPPP
> 9. AENOR / DE / ILOTV / BLU / DGIIO
> 10. AEHRS / CENPRR / EIVX / DIPU / CMOT / DENNO

*(3,3,7,2,1,1,3,5,5,5)*

**(1,2,4,1,1,2,4,2,5,7)**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word we are looking for is:

> COMPLETION!

> Each list is an anagrammed set of words where each word is missing one letter. The missing letters from each word spell out another member of the set.
>  For example, ACENT + S anagrams to SECANT.

ACENT / CENOS / AEGNTT / ACGNNOTT

> Trigonometry:
>  *S*ECANT / COS*I*NE / TA*N*GENT / COTANG*E*NT > SINE

EEEJNSWY / AEEHIMNPRSW / AACHILNNORRT / AAEERLW / KNORWY / AGIINRV / AACEHMSSSTTU / AAEINNNPSVY / EGGIOR / CCCEINOTTU / AALMNRY

> 13 Colonies:
>  NEWJE*R*SEY / NEW*H*AMPSHIRE / N*O*RTHCAROLINA / *D*ELAWARE / N*E*WYORK / VIRGIN*I*A / MASSACHUSETT*S* / PENNSY*L*VANIA / GEORGI*A* / CON*N*ECTICUT / MARYLAN*D* > RHODE ISLAND

AACDEEHLLOOPRRSST / ACT / GMPSY / CDMNRUU / AQTUZ / ACCELT / AOPZ / AAIPTT

> Moh's scale
>  ORTHOCLASE *F*ELDSPAR / TA*L*C / GYPS*U*M / C*O*RUNDUM / QUA*R*TZ / CALC*I*TE / *T*OPAZ / APATIT*E* > FLUORITE

AHLLOW / CEERSS / EHINPX / AAABKZ / FIR

> Harry Potter Title Endings
>  HALLOW*S* / SECRE*T*S / PH*O*ENIX / AZKABA*N* / FIR*E* > STONE

AIINU / HOU / AAEHKLOO / IMU / AAKU / AKLMOO

> Hawaiian Islands
>  NII*H*AU / O*A*HU / KAHAOOLA*W*E / M*A*UI / KAUA*I*  MOLOKA*I* > HAWAII

DNOR / KNOPTY / AENNOOSS / ENNX / ENO

> Noble elements:
>  R*A*DON/ K*R*YPTON / O*G*ANESSON / XEN*O*N / NEO*N* > ARGON

AMR / EHRT / EIJPRU / CEMRRY / ANSUU / ESUV

> Planets:
>  MAR*S* / E*A*RTH / JUPI*T*ER / MERC*U*RY / U*R*ANUS / VE*N*US > SATURN

EIMSSW / DFOO / EGLLOS / AADFLN / BIMORR / EMRY / IIPPP

> Fellowship of the Ring:
>  S*A*MWISE / F*R*ODO / LEGOL*A*S / *G*ANDALF / BOR*O*MIR / ME*R*RY/ PIPPI*N* > ARAGORN

AENOR / DE / ILOTV / BLU / DGIIO

> Colors of the rainbow:
>  ORAN*G*E / *R*ED / VIOL*E*T / BLU*E* / I*N*DIGO > GREEN

AEHRS / CENPRR / EIVX / DIPU / CMOT / DENNO

> Reindeer:
>  *D*ASHER / PR*A*NCER / VIXE*N* / *C*UPID / COM*E*T / DONNE*R* > PRANCER

In all, we have:

> SINE, RHODEISLAND, FLUORITE, STONE, HAWAII, ARGON, SATURN, ARAGORN, GREEN, PRANCER
>  Applying the list of numbers as indexes into the words, we get:
>  (3,3,7,2,1,1,3,5,5,5)
>  N O T T H A T O N E
>  (1,2,4,1,1,2,4,2,5,7)
>  S H O N H R U R N R
>  The bottom doesn’t make sense; let’s see what was missing from each list:
>  COSECANT, SOUTHCAROLINA, DIAMOND, PRINCE, LANAI, HELIUM, NEPTUNE, GIMLI, YELLOW, BLITZEN
>  (1,2,4,1,1,2,4,2,5,7)
>  C O M P L E T I O N
>  Since the answer is a word, it’s not that (first) one; it’s COMPLETION.
>  Striving for excellence? Perfection? Success? Each list must be finished, so you are striving for completion!

Comment: Correct :) The checkmark is yours!